# Rails :: Current User Relationship with the Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a bunch of posts and I want to know if the current_user likes them. where do I put this code: controller? model? In devise there's no easy way to access the current_user from the model, and it seems really awkward to add `@posts.each {|p| p.liked_this = p.liked_this?}` to all my controllers.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the queries from the controller.

`Posts.liked_by(current_user)`

(where `liked_by` is a method in your `Post` model.)

Or you could use the [sentient_user](https://github.com/bokmann/sentient_user) gem to let your models access your current user.

In a former project we used sentient_user heavily, because our model layer cared very much about user permissions, etc.